# virtualenv command not found after installed with MacPorts

Tags: python, virtualenv, macports

I have python 2.7 installed via mac ports on a mac. I installed virtualenv via macports (py27-virtualenv @1.6.1_0 (active). When issue the command: virtualenv demo_venv --no-site-packages, I get this error: -bash: virtualenv:command not found. It's not picking virtualenv up @ all, so do I need to symlink it to my python27 location?

Comment: what do you get when you run `which virtualenv` at the bash prompt?

Comment: Nothing. It just goes back to an empty bash prompt.

Comment: okay, that means it's not in your path.

Comment: That's just what I figured. Working on fixing it now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure `virtualenv` is in your PATH, although it should be if it was installed correctly.

Comment: Im checking that now. It should be in my path, not sure why it wouldn't be. Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

As you noted, MacPorts offers several versions of pyXX-virtualenv packages.  You need to tell MacPorts which of those versions you want to use by default:

```
port select --list virtualenv
port select --set virtualenv virtualenv27
which virtualenv
```

After this, you should be able to just type `virtualenv` (assuming the MacPorts bin directory is in your path).

Comment: This answer should be the one marked as correct. This is the right way to handle this in MacPorts.

Comment: This is the correct way, indeed. Also, for zsh users, make sure you issue a `rehash` after doing `port select`.

Answer (score 4):

The command is `virtualenv-2.7`, not just `virtualenv`.

If you look at the package contents, you can see that no executable named `virtualenv` is installed.

Answer (score 3):

MacPorts installs versioned links to `virtualenv` in `/opt/local/bin`, the default location for MacPorts.  When using MacPorts, you need to ensure `/opt/local/bin` is on your shell PATH environment variable.  Here, I show both `py26-virtualenv` and `py27-virtualenv` installed:

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Developer/Tools
$ ls -l /opt/local/bin/virtuale*
lrwxr-x---  1 root  admin  13 Oct 15  2009 /opt/local/bin/virtualenv@ -> virtualenv2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 May 17 02:20 /opt/local/bin/virtualenv-2.6@ -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/virtualenv
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 May 17 02:29 /opt/local/bin/virtualenv-2.7@ -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  88 Jun 27  2010 /opt/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_bashrc-2.6@ -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/virtualenvw
```

In general, if you want to know what files a MacPort port installs and where, use `port contents` to find out:

```
$ port contents py27-virtualenv
Port py27-virtualenv contains:
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.1-py2.7.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.1-py2.7.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.1-py2.7.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.1-py2.7.egg-info/entry_points.txt
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.1-py2.7.egg-info/not-zip-safe
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.6.1-py2.7.egg-info/top_level.txt
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.pyc
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/__init__.py
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/__init__.pyc
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/distribute-0.6.16.tar.gz
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.0.1.tar.gz
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
  /opt/local/bin/virtualenv-2.7
  /opt/local/share/doc/py27-virtualenv/index.txt
  /opt/local/share/doc/py27-virtualenv/news.txt
```

Comment: when I do: port contents py27-virtualenv I get exactly what you have. Python2.7 runs fine & py27-virtualenv says it's installed and (active) via macports. When I go: which virtualenv I still get an empty bash shell upon return. I tried a symlink: sudo ln -s /opt/local/var/macports/software/py27-virutalenv /opt/local/bin & it's still not working. I initially tried the symlink without the sudo but I got permission denied. Macports I assume doesn't like that. I have this set up running fine on another mac but this one has been a pain in the butt. Im not sure what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: I also get this: -- demetriusford$ ls -l /opt/local/bin/virtuale*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  74 Jul  6 16:27 /opt/local/bin/virtualenv-2.7 -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv

Comment: Does your `PATH` include `/opt/local/bin`?  Do you activate the environment after it is created?  Try this:  `/opt/local/bin/virtualenv-2.7 my_ve ; source ./my_ve/bin/activate`.  If that doesn't work, show exactly what results you are seeing.

Comment: Ned that works. I have another machine with python27 & py27-virtualenv installed & I am using: virtualenv demo_venv --no-site-packages ; source demo_venv/bin/activate & it works just fine. On this new mac set up it doesn't work, but the command you gave works like a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add `/opt/local/bin` to your shell start up file, for example, add something likt this to `~/.bash_profile`:  `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin`.  (By the way, you know you can change which answer you accept :=) )

Answer (score 2):

If you use virtualenvwrapper you can configure your shell environment to point to the correct virtualenv script. Install the py27-virtualenvwrapper port and add these lines to your Bash profile:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/opt/local/bin/virtualenv-2.7
source /opt/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh-2.7
```

No other path hackery or symlinks should be required when you use the virtualenvwrapper commands:

```
% mkvirtualenv demo_venv --no-site-packages
```